# FFmpeg: move moov atom of stream to front and send result to stdout

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to extract a thumbnail image from an input stream with FFmpeg and send the result to stdout. I've been using this command: `ffmpeg -i - -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -`. This works just fine when the input has an MP4 container but not for MOV. I'm getting an "unspecified pixel format" error.

After moving the moov atom to the front of the file with this command: `ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags faststart out.mov`, and then piping the file to the previous command, everything works as expected. However, I would like to do this without writing a new file to disk. The command `ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags faststart -f mov -` fails to initialize the output stream because muxer does not support non-seekable output.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing a file, perhaps by using a buffer? I'm quite new to FFmpeg, so I might be missing something with my approach. Note that I've also tried a fragmented output: `ffmpeg -i - -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mov -` but I'm getting the same "unspecified pixel format" error when doing so.